Error Deployment Failure: No Uploaded Artifact Found
I am attempting to deploy pages with the specified configuration, an error occurred due to the absence of any uploaded artifact. The deployment process couldn't find the artifact named "coverage-report" as specified in the deployment action. But in the pipeline and in output i can see that there is an artifact uploaded with the name of "coverage-report", even the Artifact ID is also created.
This is my pipeline logs:-
> Run actions/upload-artifact@v4
  
With the provided path, there will be 1 file uploaded
Artifact 'coverage-report' (ID: 1512371137) deleted
Artifact name is valid!
Root directory input is valid!
Beginning upload of artifact content to blob storage
Uploaded bytes 3503
Finished uploading artifact content to blob storage!
SHA256 hash of uploaded artifact zip is 16b48eb6ed684e0aba7f41fff8da8ed05e28183b97c4c08f19c0b6aa063caf0c
Finalizing artifact upload
Artifact coverage-report.zip successfully finalized. Artifact ID 1518618736
Artifact coverage-report has been successfully uploaded! Final size is 3503 bytes. Artifact ID is 1518618736
Artifact download URL: https://github.com/Sonichigo/mux-postgresQL/actions/runs/9123784355/artifacts/1518618736

> Run actions/deploy-pages@v3
  with:
    artifact_name: coverage-report
    token: ***
    timeout: 600000
    error_count: 10
    reporting_interval: 5000
    preview: false
  
Artifact exchange URL: https://pipelinesghubeus10.actions.githubusercontent.com/RyaceIjGjj5Wyj3ugxgIox9jX04VXetUleDwfBLlpVjSqp5WgH/_apis/pipelines/workflows/9123784355/artifacts?api-version=6.0-preview
Error: Error: No uploaded artifact was found! Please check if there are any errors at build step, or uploaded artifact name is correct.
    at getSignedArtifactMetadata (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/deploy-pages/v3/src/internal/api-client.js:94:1)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at Deployment.create (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/deploy-pages/v3/src/internal/deployment.js:68:1)
    at main (/home/runner/work/_actions/actions/deploy-pages/v3/src/index.js:30:1)

This is my custom action.yml
outputs:
  coverage-report-file:
    description: 'Path to the generated coverage report file'
    value: ${{ steps.generate-report.outputs.report-file }}

runs:
  using: 'composite'
  steps:
    - name: Checkout repository
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up Go
      uses: actions/setup-go@v4
      with:
        go-version: 1.22.*

    - name: Generate coverage report
      id: generate-report
      run: |
        PKG_DIR="${{ inputs.package-directory || './...' }}"
        COVERAGE_FILE="${{ inputs.coverage-file || 'coverage-report' }}"
        go test -race -coverprofile=$COVERAGE_FILE.out $PKG_DIR
        go tool cover -html=$COVERAGE_FILE.out -o $COVERAGE_FILE.html
        COVERAGE_PERCENTAGE=$(go tool cover -func=$COVERAGE_FILE.out | grep total: | awk '{print substr($3, 1, length($3)-1)}')
        if (( $(echo "$COVERAGE_PERCENTAGE < ${{ inputs.coverage-threshold }}" | bc -l) )); then
          echo "Error: Coverage $COVERAGE_PERCENTAGE% is below the required threshold of ${{ inputs.coverage-threshold }}%"
          exit 1
        fi
        echo "report-file=$COVERAGE_FILE.html" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
      shell: bash

    - name: Upload coverage report artifact
      id: upload-artifact
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
      with:
        name: coverage-report
        path: ${{ steps.generate-report.outputs.report-file }}
        overwrite: true
        retention-days: 4

    - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
      id: deployment
      uses: actions/deploy-pages@v3
      with: 
        artifact_name: coverage-report
        token: ${{ github.token }}

EDIT
After updating the version of deploy-page to v4 from v3, the artifact is found but it's not able to deploy the pages, here are by debug logs:-
##[debug]}
Found 6 artifact(s)
##[debug]List artifact count: 1
##[debug]Artifact: {"name":"coverage-report","id":1521553372,"size":3503,"createdAt":"2024-05-21T05:02:05.000Z"}
Creating Pages deployment with payload:
{
    "artifact_id": 1521553372,
    "pages_build_version": "d342d0b590a3c5b2b61582d58165336bff9eeab6",
    "oidc_token": "***"
}
Created deployment for d342d0b590a3c5b2b61582d58165336bff9eeab6, ID: d342d0b590a3c5b2b61582d58165336bff9eeab6
##[debug]{"id":"d342d0b590a3c5b2b61582d58165336bff9eeab6","page_url":"https://sonichigo.github.io/mux-postgresQL/","status_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Sonichigo/mux-postgresQL/pages/deployment/status/d342d0b590a3c5b2b61582d58165336bff9eeab6","preview_url":""}
Getting Pages deployment status...
Error: Deployment failed, try again later.
##[debug]Node Action run completed with exit code 1
##[debug]Set output page_url = https://sonichigo.github.io/mux-postgresQL/
##[debug]Finished: run
##[debug]Evaluating condition for step: 'run'


I suspect it to be related to the actions/deploy-pages version. Could you try using actions/deploy-pages@v4 instead of v3? The same behavior occurs for the upload and download actions

Looks the issue was with v3. I updated it to v4 and now get thisError: Deployment failed, try again later. Although, this was interesting to notice that both version should be same.

Was the error message only Error: Deployment failed, try again later? Or did it give more details? Update your question with this message please so that we could investigate :)

There was just this message! Thanks for reminding I forgot to update the question above!

It seems you need to grant the github.token some permissions in the workflow as well to use this action: pages: write and id-token: write. Check the usage example.

when calling the action i have added the permissions see here:- workflow

According to the log, it seems your error is now related to the setup-go action you're calling in your composite action here.

This is the latest log.

It now seems to work as expected until the actions/deploy-pages@v4 action process. I'm not familiar with this action, but it seems the preview input is in alpha, and your url env variable is empty.

yes, preview seems to be in alpha and after the page is deployed ideally url should be present, right now i'm trying to use upload-page-artifact, and trying deployment with it.

@GuiFalourd upload-page-artifact worked for the deployment. But with certain changes to the workflow, i'll add the answer after final tryout.

This worked for me: -
  - name: Upload coverage report artifact
      id: upload-artifact
      uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@main
      with:
        name: github-pages

    - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
      id: deployment
      if: ${{ github.event_name == 'pull_request' }}
      uses: actions/deploy-pages@v4
      env:
        name: github-pages
        url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
      with: 
        artifact_name: github-pages
        token: ${{ github.token }}
        preview: true

So the deployment was failing due to some issue with the artifact contents/creation. I got to know that the actions/upload-pages-artifact action is recommended to be used here when aiming to deploy to Pages. Although  if above action is used then, one extra is to delete the previous github artifact otherwise it would fail since it doesn't have overwrite flag which was present in upload-artifact.
